# Generate Random Character's

Tags: python, loops, random, character

Generate N * N Random character .

I will make code perfect but it's not working .

pls any one help men.

```
import random

n=int(input("Enter a number :"))

matrix = []

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        temp = chr(random.randrange(33,126))
        if temp in matrix:
            j-=1
        else:
            matrix.append(temp)
        
print(matrix,len(matrix))
```

n = 4
I want 16 random character.

n = 5 ['a' , '@' , '5' ......] upto 25 characters I want.

Comment: So you want a list with N * N elements

Comment: Do you want a 1-dimensional list of N*N elements or 2-dimensional - i.e., N elements each of N random characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

n = int(input("Enter a Number: "))

random_nums = [random.randint(33,127) for i in range(n*n)] 
matrix = [chr(i) for i in random_nums]

print(matrix, len(matrix))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `random.sample`

```
import random
choices = "".join(chr(i) for i in range(33, 127))
k = 6
print([random.sample(choices, (k**2)%(len(choices)-1)) for i in range(0, k**2, len(choices))][0])
 # output : ['d', 'H', 'u', 'g', '2', 'j', 'z', '0', '#', 'x', '4', 'h', '`', '{', 'r', '5', 'V', 'A', '=', '"', 'f', 'n', 'p', ',', 'k', 'o', '*', '+', '3', 'S', 'U', '_', 's', 'Y', 'y', 'P']
```

Comment: Your solution gives an error if `k**2` is bigger than `len(choices)`

Comment: @KillerRebooted Now it will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to build an N * N matrix. If so then:

```
from random import choices as CHOICES

CHARS = [chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)]

N = int(input('Input N: '))

matrix = [CHOICES(CHARS, k=N) for _ in range(N)]

print(matrix)
```

**Possible output:**

```
[['N', '%', '+', 'u'], ['_', '8', 'T', '.'], ['8', '1', '=', 'O'], ['8', 'G', 'T', 'I']]
```

Comment: He just wants a matrix with N*N characters. So if `n = 4`, he wants a list with 16 random characters. Not list with 4 Rows and 4 Columns

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Not now it doesn't